# Adding to Package - Data not Available

Tags: apex, package

I'm trying to add the componets for a new package and I got this error:

> The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due
>   to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the
>   data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support
>   page.

This is a developer edition org. Any ideas about it? I've tried to add Apex Classes, Tabs, Visualforce and anyone is working.

Answer (score -1):

How do you have yourself configured if you go into `Personal Setup -> My Personal Information -> Personal Information?` Do you have the `System Administrator Profile` enabled and the `Development Mode checkbox` checked? You'll want to make certain you do **both**. I recommend you also check the `Show ViewState in Development Mode` box as well.

I'd expect doing those things will likely solve your problems.

Comment: There is nothing happening by this.

Comment: @TarachandKarwal This is a 3 yr old question. I'd be looking at the namespace for the org and the package to make certain they match the package you've specified you want to create. This is especially true now the people are creating packages in lightning orgs using MyDomain.